# Text input boxes keep changing position when error message appears

Tags: html, css, validation, input

The input boxes move up when the error message appears at the bottom . The error message is enclosed in a span tag
When the input boxes are blank and the user tries to hit enter the  error message should appear below the input box asking the user to enter the valid input , however when the input appears it moves the boxes up no longer aligning the two boxes when one is valid and the other invalid . I want it so that the error message occurs without moving changing the position of the input boxes

```css
.inputs-account > label {
   font-size: 16px;
}

.name-inputs {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: end;
}

.first-name-input {
   margin-right: 15px;
}

.inputs > .required {
   float: none;

}

.inputs > * {
   float: left;
   clear: both;
}

.inputs.reversed > * {
   float: none;
}

.inputs input[type="text"],
.inputs input[type="password"],
.inputs input[type="email"],
.inputs input[type="tel"],
.inputs select,
.inputs textarea {
   height: 45px;
   color: #12110C;
   border-radius: 3px;
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   border: 1px solid #D1DCE1;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="name-inputs inputs-account">
      <div class="inputs inputs-account first-name-input">
       <label for="FirstName">First name</label>
         <input class="key-change valid" type="text" data-val="true" data-val- 
             required="First name is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" 
               value="userName" aria-describedby="FirstName-error" aria-invalid="false">
                 <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data- 
                   valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>

   <div class="inputs inputs-account">
     <label for="LastName">Last name</label>
       <input class="key-change input-validation-error" type="text" data-val="true" 
          data-val-required="Last name is required." id="LastName" name="LastName" 
           value="" aria-describedby="LastName-error" aria-invalid="true">
              <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data- 
                  valmsg-replace="true">
                    <span id="LastName-error" class="">Last name is required.</span> 
                </span>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: welcome ot SO – please provide a usable example, for example by using a "snippet" in the editor – you can fill in CSS, HTML and JS so we can see all relevant pieces

Comment: Problem seems to disappear as soon as you remove `align-items: end;` from `.name-inputs` ...? If that does not solve it for you because you have more groups of such fields or something, then please show an actual example for that.

Comment: `.inputs { align-self: flex-start; }`

Answer (score 1):

set `align-items: start;` for `.name-inputs` class.

```css
.inputs-account > label {
   font-size: 16px;
}

.name-inputs {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   align-items: start;
}

.first-name-input {
   margin-right: 15px;
}

.inputs > .required {
   float: none;

}

.inputs > * {
   float: left;
   clear: both;
}

.inputs.reversed > * {
   float: none;
}

.inputs input[type="text"],
.inputs input[type="password"],
.inputs input[type="email"],
.inputs input[type="tel"],
.inputs select,
.inputs textarea {
   height: 45px;
   color: #12110C;
   border-radius: 3px;
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   border: 1px solid #D1DCE1;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="name-inputs inputs-account">
      <div class="inputs inputs-account first-name-input">
       <label for="FirstName">First name</label>
         <input class="key-change valid" type="text" data-val="true" data-val- 
             required="First name is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" 
               value="userName" aria-describedby="FirstName-error" aria-invalid="false">
                 <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data- 
                   valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                </div>

   <div class="inputs inputs-account">
     <label for="LastName">Last name</label>
       <input class="key-change input-validation-error" type="text" data-val="true" 
          data-val-required="Last name is required." id="LastName" name="LastName" 
           value="" aria-describedby="LastName-error" aria-invalid="true">
              <span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data- 
                  valmsg-replace="true">
                    <span id="LastName-error" class="">Last name is required.</span> 
                </span>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Setting `align-items: start` on `.name-inputs` should cause any error message that appears to expand the `.inputs` div without affecting the alignment of the inputs because they are already at the top of their parent container.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to use an error message under the fields then it will move the field up. As an alternative, you can use the bootstrap form-control class. It will help you to achieve the same thing you want to.

Leaving a link below of a codepen js form validation -
{https://codepen.io/AbdullahSajjad/pen/LYGVRgK}

Hope this works.